# Is there a name for arrows not in the image of a nonfull functor?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, functors

Given a functor $F$ which is not full, there may be arrows $f : FA \to FB$ which are not of the form $F \tilde{f}$ for any $\tilde{f} : A \to B$.

I have been calling these arrows "nonstandard", but I am curious if there is an accepted terminology for them. In particular, it would be nice to have something to google to see if any of my results are corollaries of other theorems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard terminology for anything like this; similarly I'm not aware of any standard terminology for an element not in the image of a non-surjective group homomorphism, etc. What do you want this for?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I have a monadic functor on the category of graphs and I'm trying to understand all the ways one free algebra can embed in another. Since the free functor isn't full, there are lots of these "nonstandard" monomorphisms, and I am curious if there are category theoretic ways of studying this problem, or if I need to do "real work". In particular, it's not clear when a mono $m : \Gamma \to RL\Delta$ of graphs induces a mono $\tilde{m} : L\Gamma \to L\Delta$. (Here $L \dashv R$ induces my monad). I haven't found anything, but that might be a lack of terminology... I guess not, though

Comment: I'm not aware of, for example, any abstract nonsense that tells you how free groups embed into other free groups; as far as I know that already requires "real work." The answer is specific to groups and doesn't generalize to other free objects. So I imagine something similar is true in your case.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: that makes sense. I thought there might be something because I'm looking into right angled artin groups, and my monad interpolates between free groups and free abelian groups (both of which are well understood, categorically and otherwise). Oh well. Thanks for the help ^_^